# Sphinx: Keep indexes up to date. Real Time Index vs. Live Index Update

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I really don't know what's the difference between both and so I don't know what I need to refresh my indexes on-the-fly whenever a change has been made to the database. That's what I want: to keep my search function up to date to the last change. Anybody can help me?

If it helps, I am using MySQL for persistence and PHP for using the API.

Comment: I am in that same situation, I will go start implementing as the follow article of sphinx explains; http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/delta-updates.html

Comment: Thank you @user968898! I read it yesterday but I couldn't figure out how it exactly works. Please, tell me whether you achieve live updates.

Comment: I will stat implementation today, if you need explanation I got msn nicky[@]omerta.min.nu

Comment: Ain't got MSN but thank you anyway!

Comment: I got it work. The principal is that main is the parent index and delta the child. These two works together. Main creates the huge index and Delta just a little index with only new records. With the MySql table you need to create you take care about the last id indexed by the main index. The delta does a lookup in that MySql table to see from where it needs to get the new records (if id is bigger than last, its a new document). With cmd you can run indexer to merge main+delta and delta will clear his index (remove documents who are added to the main index) so it keeps fast and small. clear?

Comment: Sounds good! :) Does it work for UPDATEs and DELETEs too?

Comment: Yes it should work also for that! Didn't that that yet myself but here you have some information; http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#conf-sql-query-killlist :)

Comment: Cool! If you put that as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thanks man! I hope it will helps you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal is that main is the parent index and delta the child. These two works together.

Main creates the huge index and Delta just a little index with only new records. With the MySql table you need to create you take care about the last id indexed by the main index.

The delta does a lookup in that MySql table to see from where it needs to get the new records (if id is bigger than last, its a new document). With command line you can run indexer to merge main+delta and delta will clear his index (remove documents who are added to the main index) so it keeps fast and small.

The main delta schema can handle (almost realtime) INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE